# UIActivityViewController and presentViewController generating numerous errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I recently came encountered an error with UIActivityViewController in developing in objective-c running under IOS 15.4.1 that used to work. In fact, I copied the below code form one app (where it worked) to another (where it stopped working) generating a number of errors below. On a physical device, the activity controller (for airdrop and others) pops up and then immediately pops down when these errors appear with no chance to interact. There are no issues on the Xcode Simulator and it works fine. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

-- Objective-C Code --

```
// create a message

NSString *theMessage = @"Some text we're sharing with an activity controller";

NSArray *items = @[theMessage];

// build an activity view controller

UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];

// and present it

[self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:^{
```

--- Error Log ---

```
2022-04-21 14:01:53.986049-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] shareText Some text we're sharing with an activity controller
2022-04-21 14:01:54.149992-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] [Default] Task myapp[29328]/1#4 LF=0 couldn't find entitlement CopresenceCore.Entitlement.publicAPI error nil
2022-04-21 14:01:54.410315-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] [Default] Task myapp[29328]/1#4 LF=0 couldn't find entitlement CopresenceCore.Entitlement.publicAPI error nil
2022-04-21 14:01:54.587110-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] [default] LaunchServices: store (null) or url (null) was nil: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
2022-04-21 14:01:54.587209-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] [default] Attempt to map database failed: permission was denied. This attempt will not be retried.
2022-04-21 14:01:54.587282-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
2022-04-21 14:01:54.620054-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] [default] -imageForImageDescriptor: can do IO please adopt -imageForDescriptor: for IO free drawing or -prepareImageForDescriptor: if IO is allowed. (This will become a fault soon.)
2022-04-21 14:01:54.631883-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] [LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionReusableView that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing. View: <_UIActivityContentFooterView: 0x1091b0670; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (20 288; 374 52); layer = <CALayer: 0x2813a09c0>>
2022-04-21 14:01:54.647215-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] [default] LaunchServices: store (null) or url (null) was nil: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
2022-04-21 14:01:54.647308-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] [default] Attempt to map database failed: permission was denied. This attempt will not be retried.
2022-04-21 14:01:54.647381-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
2022-04-21 14:01:54.647627-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] [default] -imageForImageDescriptor: can do IO please adopt -imageForDescriptor: for IO free drawing or -prepareImageForDescriptor: if IO is allowed. (This will become a fault soon.)
2022-04-21 14:01:55.226089-0400 myapp[29328:1429870] shareText: presentViewController completed
2022-04-21 14:01:55.761911-0400 myapp[29328:1430040] [ShareSheet] connection invalidated
```

Comment: What is `presentActivityController:`?

Comment: Per the Apple API documentation for UiViewController: /*
  The next two methods are replacements for presentModalViewController:animated and
  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: The completion handler, if provided, will be invoked after the presented
  controllers viewDidAppear: callback is invoked.
*/
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^ __nullable)(void))completion NS_SWIFT_DISABLE_ASYNC API_AVAILABLE(ios(5.0));

Comment: If possible, could you please show more of your code as we cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't understand, you copy paste from where exactly? I don't see the method of `presentActivityController` in your comment, nor in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller?language=objc. I see `-presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Comment: Because I tested the code, and I havee `No visible @interface for 'MyUIViewControllerClass' declares the selector 'presentActivityController:'`, so you implemented yourself?

Comment: Apologies folks.    The code extract referenced presentActivityController instead of  presentViewController.   presentActivityController was user defined but essentially all it did was call presentViewController in this case.**However, the error still remains. (I have updated the original post accordingly).

Answer (score -1):

The cause of this problem was that after displaying the ActivityViewController in one code execution thread, another thread in the same app was dismissing the ActivityViewController.

I found the issue by setting a symbolic breakpoint at -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] and then examining the stack trace to find which thread was dismissing the ActivityViewController.

What was confusing was there are still error messages in the console but these are unrelated to the problem.    By looking at other message posts, this seems to be log noise and to ignore it. Example of these error messages are: "Attempt to map database failed: permission was denied. This attempt will not be retried." or "-imageForImageDescriptor: can do IO please adopt -imageForDescriptor: for IO free drawing or -prepareImageForDescriptor: if IO is allowed. (This will become a fault soon.)"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's great that you solved the problem but this answer in no way grows out of the information given in the question, so this is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Need to add Context to the question, currently its just text on page.